# Runtime Permissions

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот по нажатию кнопки следующим образом:

```
 private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        //openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Thu Aug 29 10:42:39 GMT 2019.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Про runtime permissions в курсе, запрашиваю их следующим образом используя dexter:

```
private void requestPermissions(){
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
        @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {openMultipleThings();}
        @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {}
    }).check();
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, разрешения имеются, как на эмуляторе, так и на физ.устройстве, дислокацию записи изображений менять тоже пробовал.

Comment: можно попробовать перед тем как сделать скриншот проверять есть ли разрешение и если нету то запрашивать его, и потом уже делать скриншот

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko в этом случае ситуация не изменяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "myFile.txt";

File f = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
```